# bsnl is709c android tablet is not booting up

Tags: factory-reset, stock-android, hard-reset

My **BSNL penta IS709C** tablet got locked after too many unlock attempts. After that I tried to hard reset by pressing BACK + HOME + MENU buttons together with the power button but in vain. 
Tablet present condition:

1) USB debugging off, so no adb commands. 
 2) wifi is off. 
3) No
    associated google account.

Please help me restore the tablet or suggest me how can I hard reset it.

[image: BSNL IS709C]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after battling for two days, finally I have managed to solved this problem.

First of all download stock ROM for your tablet from [here](http://androidxda.com/download-bsnl-stock-rom-models)
and extract the file anywhere you want.

**Note**:- All the below steps are provided in .ppt file which you can find in the downloaded zip folder(here ..\BSNL-IS709C\BSNL IS709C\Firmware\upgrade\tool). Since it is a Chinese version so I thought it might help if I re-write the steps here:

- Shut down your tablet.
- take out your SDCard if you don't want data loss.
- Plug one end of the Usb cable to PC/Laptop.
- Press the middle button(namely menu button) of the three buttons on the tablet and the power button together and then plug another end of the Usb cable to the tablet.
- After this, your computer will try to install drivers for your device which you can ignore because you are gonna install the drivers manually.
- go to device manager->Other devices->right click on the unknown device(which is yours with yellow triangle) and then click on update driver software.
- Choose to manually locate drivers and move to this directory (**..\BSNL-IS709C\BSNL IS709C\Firmware\upgrade\tool\Driver**).
- Select the appropriate driver(**x86/x64**) and click OK, a red color pop up is displayed. Click yes(or whatever) to install the drivers.
- Now open the **RKBatchTool** provided here(**..BSNL-IS709C\BSNL IS709C\Firmware\upgrade\tool**). You will see a green color square on it which means that it has recognized your device. Meanwhile is the Chinese version, so can refer this picture for further operation:

[image]

- Click on the **Restore** button to factory reset the tablet and when its done. Click on upgrade.
- Restart the tablet and voila, its done!!